# Forcing $\pi_1(\tilde f(a))=f(a)$ for an object of a sigma type

Tags: logic, computer-science, first-order-logic, proof-theory, type-theory

Suppose I have an object $f$ of type $\Pi x:A.B(x)$, and consider a new type $\Pi (x:A).\Sigma (t:B(x)).C(t)$. If $\tilde f$ is an object of the second type and $a:A$, then $\pi_1(\tilde f (a)):B(x)$, where $\pi_1(x,y)=x$. Is there a way to force that $\pi_1(\tilde f(a))=f(a)$?

A few words on where this question is coming from: suppose we want to model sentences like "John walked" and "John walked (for some time) and then stopped". Say $walk$ has type $\Pi x:AnimateEntity.Evt(x)$, so $walk(john)$ has type $Evt(john)$, the type of events with participant "John". Now consider another version of the verb "walk", one in which it is encoded that the action of walking took place and then stopped (in some languages there is such a word form). Let's call this version $walk'$. Then it would be natural to assume that $walk'(john):\Sigma (x:Evt(j)).Stop(x)$, where $\pi_1(walk'(john)) = walk(john)$ -- which says that there was the original walking event (which we denoted $walk$ without a prime) and $\pi_2(walk'(john))$ is a proof that that original walking event stopped. So if I want $walk'(john)$ to have that type, I should make $walk'$ have type $\Pi (x:AnimateEntity).\Sigma(t:Evt(x)).Stop(t)$. But now I'm not sure how to force $\pi_1(walk'(john)) = walk(john)$, and hence the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I answer (the purely mathematical part of) your question, we have to get around a minor, but confusing, notational ambiguity.

It's not entirely clear what role you intend $C$ to play. Is it some *bona fide* function of type $C: \Pi x:A.B(x) \rightarrow \mathrm{Type}$? If so, why do you elide the $x$ and not denote its value at least $C(x)(t)$? If not, does it just abbreviate whatever expression, with free variable $t$, comes after the $\Sigma$ binder? Then why not just denote it $C$ instead of $C(t)$? I'm going to assume $C$ is the former.

1. In general, when $A: \mathrm{Type}$, $B: A \rightarrow \mathrm{Type}$, $f: \Pi x:A.B(x)$ and $C: \Pi x:A.B(x) \rightarrow \mathrm{Type}$ are arbitrary, there is no way to force this. Consider e.g. the situation where $C(x)(t)$ stands for $f(x) \neq t$.
2. When $A: \mathrm{Type}$, $B: A \rightarrow \mathrm{Type}$, $f: \Pi x:A.B(x)$, but you have full control over $C$, you can achieve what you want trivially: just make sure that $C(x)(t)$ has the form $(t = f(x)) \times C'(x)(t)$ for some $C': \Pi x:A. B(x) \rightarrow \mathrm{Type}$.
3. Inbetween the two extreme scenarios above, when you *know some things* about $C$, but don't have full control over it, you *might* be able to ensure this, depending on the properties of $C$. Unfortunately, I cannot answer your question in the context of Corfield-style HoTT linguistics, concerning $\mathrm{Stop}$ in particular; and I'll be surprised if anyone apart from perhaps [David Corfield](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/368788/david-corfield) can.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think by $C$ I just meant a family of types $B(x)\to Type$. As far as I know, the notation $\Sigma t:B.C(t)$ (where $C: B \to Type$ is a family of types) is standard, and I intended to use this notation, except that in my case $B$ also depends on some other variable. I don't exactly get how $C$ could have the type you mention, $\Pi x:A.\Sigma t:B(x).Type$. I thought if the notation $\Sigma t:B.C(t)$ appears (which it does in my case, except that I have $B(x)$ instead of $B$), this presupposes that $C: B\to Type$. As a result, I don't quite get the second bullet point.

Comment: (And also even if $C$ had the type you mentioned, I don't understand why the expression $C(x)(t)$ would be meaningful. $C(x)$ would have type $\Sigma t:B(x).Type$, and since it's not a $\Pi$ type, I don't understand how we could apply $t$ to $C(x)$.)

Comment: One of the three times I wrote down the type of $C$ had a copy-paste error (unfortunately it was the very first time). The other two instances were correct. I fixed it in the edit, see if it makes more sense now.

Comment: Wgile the notation Σt:B.C(t) (where C:B→Type is a family of types) is standard, above B is not a type, but rather an indexed family of types. And having $C : B(x) \rightarrow \mathrm{Type}$ would not work, as it contains $x$ free. You need to make sure that $C(t)$ makes sense, and that requires the $x$ bound by the $\Pi$ to coincude with the $x$ that occurs free in the type of $C$ .

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. But I still can't see how making $C(x)(t)$ be of the form $(t=f(x))\times C'(x)(t)$ helps. In this case, $\tilde f$ has type $\Pi x:A. \Sigma t:B(x). [(t=f(x)) \times C'(x)(t)]$, how does this help us with showing that $\pi_1(\tilde f(a))=f(a)$?

Comment: If $\tilde f : \Pi x:A. \Sigma t : B(x). t = f(x) \times C'(x)(t)$, then $\tilde f(a) : \Sigma t : B(x). t = f(a) \times C'(a)(t)$, and so $\pi_2 (\tilde f(a)) : \pi_1(\tilde f(a)) = f(a) \times C'(a)( \pi_1(\tilde f(a)) )$; consequently, $\pi_1 (\pi_2 (\tilde f(a))) : \pi_1(\tilde f(a)) = f(a)$ is the proof you're looking for.

Comment: Just to clarify, if treat $x$ as a constant as opposed to a variable (for example, in the Edinburgh Logical Framework, constants are declared in "signatures" and variables are declared in "contexts"), then $C:B(x)\to Type$ would be a well-formed judgement, right?

Comment: @user125234 I regret to say that I don't know. I've never used LF for anything, and am only vaguely aware of it.